# Convert dates string to different format with javascript

Tags: javascript, string-formatting, google-calendar-api

This is what I have in a script that is pulling events with a Google Calendar API:

```
var datestring2 = (startJSDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + startJSDate.getDate();
```

After I append this to a list it prints out in the format `12/2` while I want it to print out  `Friday, Dec 2`.

How can I do this? I have looked into `date.js` but had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in function in Javascript that can do that (I presume you are after something like PHP's `date()` function).

You can certainly roll your own solution as other answers have suggested, but unless you are really against it, date.js is great for this.

You can use the libraries `toString()` function to get formatted date strings like so:

```
Date.today().toString("d-MMM-yyyy");
```

More information can be found in the [DateJS API documention](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString).

Comment: To get `Friday, Dec 2` using [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/), try `startJSDate.toString("dddd, MMM d")`. See the [FormatSpecifiers doc](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) for more formatting options. (There is a link that page in the doc for the `toString` function beeglebug mentions, but I keep forgetting how to find it.)

Comment: startJSDate.toString("dddd, MMM d")
displays
Sun Dec 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (cst)
how do I get rid of "00:00:00 GMT-0600 (cst)"

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', ...];
var ordinals = {1:'st', 21:'st', 31:'st', 2:'nd', 22:'nd', 3:'rd', 23:'rd'};  
var m = startJSDate.getMonth();
var d = startJSDate.getDate();
var s = months[m] + ', ' + s + (ordinals[s] || 'th');
```

Comment: how can it find if what day of the week it is? i.e. "Friday"

Answer (score 0):

This article has some great examples on printing out [dates in javacript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/javascript_date_and_time.php3)

And from there you want something like this

```
var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
 "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDay();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var sup = "";
if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date ==31)
{
    sup = "st";
}
else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22)
{
    sup = "nd";
}
else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23)
{
    sup = "rd";
}
else
{
   sup = "th";
}

var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

datestring2 = d_names[curr_day] + ", " + m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_date + sup );
```

Will give you Thursday, December 1st

Comment: var l2 = document.createElement('li');

Comment: //this appends it to the list

var l2 = document.createElement('li');
 l2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datestring2));  
also im trying to I'm now trying to go from "10/2"
to "Friday, Dec 2011"

Comment: If you look at the article I [linked originally](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/getting_current_time_using_javascript.php3) it shows you a way to do it as "Friday, Dec 2011" as well, its about constructing the arrays with the values in such as the Months and Days and using array indexers to pull them out.

Comment: See slightly modified answer, just change the months array to the shorthand if you want it that way and remove the `sup` variable if you don't want the `nd` or respective one for each month