# Javascript convert date to different format

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date picker which is in the format of `31-Dec-2014` as this is the format everyone is familiar with on our tool.

I am trying to convert it to a JavaScript date object in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy` but I am having a little trouble.

I tried something simple like `var startDate = new Date('31-Dec-2014');` but it outputs invalid date.

I know there are plugins out there like `date.js` and `moment.js` but I feel like this would be simple to do without it.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert dates string to different format with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338381/convert-dates-string-to-different-format-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338381/convert-dates-string-to-different-format-with-javascript

Comment: You can't expect `Date` to parse dates with custom syntax. Either use a standard syntax, or use a library to have more flexibility, or parse it manually.

Comment: If you pass a string to `Date` then it need to be `[...]A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).` [MDN: Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 3 param version of [***Date***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and translate your month code to the correct number, e.g.

```
function myDate(input) {
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    input = input.split('-');
    input[1] = months.indexOf(input[1]);
    return new Date(+input[2], +input[1], +input[0]);
}

myDate('31-Dec-2014'); // Wed Dec 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Please remember all dates are generated in the client's local timezone, you may want to use the *UTC* methods instead.